# Remove duplicates pair in an array and also in reverse order PHP Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
array:2 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        0 => 159
        1 => 158
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        0 => 159
        1 => 158
      ]
      2 => array:2 [▼
        0 => 158
        1 => 159
      ]
    ]
```

I want to delete the duplicate ones and the duplicate in reverse order. For example index `0` and index `1` has the same values `159 and 158` also same in order like `0 => 159` and `1 => 158` . I want to delete either index `1` or `0`. Since it is same. And if you noticed index `2`. it has the same value only difference is the order `0 => 158` and `1 => 159` I also want to delete this since it is the same pair values. How can I do that if that array is `$remove_arr`

So since I will delete index `2` and either index `0` or `1` there should only be one index left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count(array_intersect()) gets the amount of the same items in the array. 
When it equal the array lenght, remove one of them

```
$remove_arr = [
[158, 159],
[158, 159],
[159, 158]
];

for($i = count($remove_arr)-1; $i >= 0 ; $i--) {
   $j = $i-1; 
   while ($j >= 0) { 
      if (count(array_intersect($remove_arr[$i],$remove_arr[$j])) == count($remove_arr[$i]))
           { unset($remove_arr[$i]); break; }
       else $j--;
   }
}

print_r($remove_arr);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter solution:

```
$data = [[158, 159], [158, 159], [159, 158]];

$unique = array_unique(array_map(function ($item) {
    sort($item); return $item;
}, $data), SORT_REGULAR);

dump($unique); // This will output [[158, 159]]
```

This solution sorts the contents of the level 2 arrays. So after sorting, the last value will also become `[158, 159]` so it can be correctly evaluated by [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-unique.php) as a duplicate.

Comment: I did not have a step up this variant :). +1